# Find the value of $f(2009)$ if $f(x-y)=\sqrt{f(xy)+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, functional-equations

Disclaimer: I don't know what the source of this problem is, but I would guess it's from a ([non-Putnam](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2009.pdf)) 2009 contest.

> Let $f(x)$ be a function defined for all positive real numbers satisfying the conditions,
>
> - $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, and
> - $f(x-y)=\sqrt{f(xy)+1}$ for all $x>y>0$.
>
> Find the value of $f(2009)$.

If I set $x=1$ and $y=\frac12$, then I find

$$f\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt{f\left(\frac12\right)+1}\implies f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$$

Then I figured that, if I can find a solution to

$$\begin{cases}x-y=\frac12\\[1ex]xy=n&(n>0)\end{cases},$$

then I can always find the value of $f(n)$ in terms of $f\left(\frac12\right)$. In particular,

$$f(2009)=f\left(\frac12\right)^2-1=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2,$$

and moreover, it would seem $f(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ for all values of $x>\frac12$. (This condition comes from the solution set for [$x-y=\frac12,x>y>0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-y%3D1%2F2,+x%3Ey%3E0)). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. There is always a solution to
$$
  \begin{align*}
    x - y & = \frac{1}{2} \\
    xy & = n.
  \end{align*}
$$

It is given by
$$
  x = \frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{n + \frac{1}{16}} \quad \text{and} \quad y = -\frac{1}{4} + \sqrt{n + \frac{1}{16}}.
$$

This was found by noting that $x$ and $-y$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$
  \lambda^2 - \frac{1}{2} \lambda - n = 0
$$
and using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Yep. This was exactly what I was about to post. You did it faster ;-)